# Magento 2 : Error while creating credit memo for shipment using a custom script

Tags: magento2, creditmemo

Error - **If the invoice was created offline, try creating an offline credit memo**

I am getting above error when refunding shipping amount "online".

Can anybody please explain me why i am getting this error also in which case this error can appear ?

BTW - I am using custom script that refund shipment amount online.

Thankyou

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: please add some more details like logs or screenshots as well as which payment method you are using

Answer (score 1):

The error you are facing, which means you have created invoice offline so there was no transaction for this invoice and that's why you are not allowed to refund online.

Online capture of depend on which payment gateway you are using. If you are using offline payment like COD, then invoice will be created offline and you have to refund offline for that invoice.

Thanks

Comment: Thankyou ZealousWeb for answer

Comment: Can you please upvote and approve?